Cppcheck error are raised on all code even with macro defined
I am running Cppcheck with MISRA-C:2012 on my project without any -D or -U options for the preprocessor. All the code is analysed on my .c file, even the part only defined under certain conditions (#ifdef MACRO1) but I dont have the same behaviour on the header, where only the code common to every MACRO is analysed.
I made an small piece of code to illustrate my problem:
test.h
void test_noConfiguration(void);

#if defined(CONFIG_1) 
void test_configuration1(void);
#endif

#if defined(CONFIG_2)
void test_configuration2(void);
#endif

test.c
#include "test.h"

static uint8_t localFunction(void)
{
    return 0U;
}

void test_noConfiguration()
{
    localFunction();
    uint8_t u8_var = 0U;
}

#if defined(CONFIG_1)
void test_configuration1()
{
    localFunction();
    uint8_t u8_var = 0U;
}
#endif

#if defined(CONFIG_2)
void test_configuration2()
{
    localFunction();
    uint8_t u8_var = 0U;
}
#endif

When the analyse is launched Cppchack with -DCONFIG_1, all the issues are raised except for the one between #if defined(CONFIG_2), both in the .c and .h files, as expected.
When the analyse is launched without any options (-D or -U) and all the issues of test.c are raised but in test.h, only the one outside #ifdef CONFIG_1 or #ifdef CONFIG_2 are raised (here, only the line with declaration of void test_noConfiguration(void); raised the error misra-c2012-8.2 in test.h)
According to the namual, without any specification the code will test as if all the configurations are used and every error should be raised.
I was wondering why the error from the header is not raised in this case.

What is ":preprocessor:" part? if it was supposed to : What does the manual say? https://cppcheck.sourceforge.io/manual.pdf check page 11 section named Automatic configuration of preprocessor defines

According to the manual and the command used, I test all configurations.
So i guess my question is why the errors in the header are not raised.

Thanks for your feedback, i edited the issue to make my question more specific.

Are those the complete c and h files? Have you tried to place #error Error somewhere where you want to have a test for error detection?

Yes those are the complete file. To test for error detection i am triggering some misra issues :

Misra 17.7: The value returned by a function having non- void return type shall be used (raised in .c files)
Misra 8.2:  Function types shall be in prototype form with named parameters (raised in .h files)

I tried to add #error Error  and an error (preprocessorErrorDirective) is raised instead of the misra errors. The behaviour is different, as this error wont be raised when the analyse is launched without any macro defined.
